# Javascript parameter to map() function

Tags: javascript

Please explain this JavaScript language construct:

```
cursor => cursor.map(doc => doc._key)
```

in this context

```
collection.all().then(
  cursor => cursor.map(doc => doc._key) // this line
).then(
  keys => console.log('All keys:', keys.join(', ')),
  err => console.error('Failed to fetch all documents:', err)
);
```

Don't understand the `doc => doc._key` as parameter to the `map()` function. Why will it not work with `doc => { key: doc._key, name: doc.name}`?

Comment: Have a look for the term arrow functions, that will answer you question.

Comment: Thanks Christos. I spent two hours searching today, didn't know they were called arrow functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break it down by line:
 Also here is some [documentation on arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
collection.all()

// give me all the documents in the collection

.then(

  cursor  

// take a cursor, which goes over each item in the collection

=> 

// you can think of this as "take the cursor as input into an anonymous function, and return..."

cursor.map(

// a map over the cursors output

doc => doc._key)

// each document the cursor finds, return the documents key

).then(

  keys => console.log('All keys:', keys.join(', ')),

// take the resulting keys, and console log their value

  err => console.error('Failed to fetch all documents:', err)

// if there are any errors, please log those as well.
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick, excellent answer. Now I will probably end up refactoring a lot of code :))

Comment: Sure! No problem. Please be careful to read through documentation though. There are some major gotcha's, including compatibility, and the meaning of "this" in context. Other than that, it's a pretty awesome syntax IMO.

Comment: Yes sir it sure is. Looks like I will have to spend a few more days reading, before jumping into node.js just like that.